# Content stream to CMIS's file without API

Tags: post, cmis

I have a fileshare server (from apache opencmis project) that I want to access directly by a web page. So by using javascript probably. My question is :

-Is it possible to work on a cmis repository using http request (like [here](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Web_Scripts_Reference#Write_Content_.28setContent.29) for alfresco server)?

I find that there is very few information on the subject.

Thanks

**edit :** Maybe my need isn't clear after reading me again. So to simplify I'm looking for a *litle* static html/javascript code. My purpose is to upload a new file to folder (I know his ObjectId) or modify content of a file.

**Ps :** Only LGPL, Apache or similar licence.

Thanks again!

Comment: The CMIS Browser Binding is RESTful and JSON based, so ought to do it with a little bit of JavaScript code around it. Is that an option?

Comment: Yes javascript is good. But I don't see how to do this. I can get a file or delete the content of a file with a little js code. But not upload content stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rudimentary example here:
https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/chemistry/opencmis/trunk/chemistry-opencmis-server/chemistry-opencmis-server-bindings-war/src/main/webapp/web/index.html?view=markup

Comment: It seems to be what I'm looking for. I downloaded chemistry-opencmis-server-bindings-war-0.11.0 (and unzip). The form of the OpenCMIS Web Interface appears. But I've some errors (in browser console) saying that cmisLogin and cmisLogout aren't defined and it can't find the script 'browser?login=script'. Where can I find this?

Comment: Get the OpenCMIS InMemory repository for testing. The URL http://<host>/<inmemory>/web opens this page.